# How to make XCode Run Script Build Phase run if the build breaks?

Tags: xcode, macos, scripting, build, build-automation

I want to be able to launch a Run Script Build Phase in XCode that does this:

/usr/bin/say "Broke it." if my build fails.

Not sure how to capture the build failure to prompt that though? Two reasons I guess, one "what to catch", two "the build is done so the script has already run in theory... ?"

How would you do this?

Thanks // :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're specifically interested in playing audio, I'd recommend converting the audio into a sound recording and playing back that audio using the `PBXBuildFailureSound` default for Xcode. Something like:

```
defaults write com.apple.Xcode PBXBuildFailureSound /path/to/sound
```

See the [Xcode User Default Reference](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/DeveloperTools/Reference/XcodeUserDefaultRef/100-Xcode_User_Defaults/UserDefaultRef.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005535-CH3-SW47) for more interesting Xcode tricks.

To convert the audio of /usr/bin/say to an aiff file using a utility like [SoundFlower](http://code.google.com/p/soundflower/) and the audio recording feature of QuickTime Player.